# "System resource exceeded" when updating recordset, and possibly at other points

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I'm experiencing an intermittent issue with an application that's Excel 2010 front-end, Access 2010 back end.  It's in use by 5-10 users simultaneously.  Recently, users have started intermittently receiving the following error:

`Run-time error '3035': System resource exceeded.`

Sometimes the Debug button is grayed out so I can't jump to the code that caused the error, but when it's available to click, it takes me to the following code:

```
 'Open connection to back end DB
 Set db = OpenDatabase(dbPath)

 'Open a recordset of a table
 Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(Tbl)

 'loop through rows in a 2D array
 For i = FR To LR
  RS.AddNew
   'loop through columns of the 2D array
   For j = 1 to LC
    'set values for various fields in the new record, using values from the array
   Next
  RS.Update
 Next
```

Here, the `RS.Update` is marked as the line that's causing the error.

What's odd is that this problem comes and goes; users will repeatedly receive it when attempting to submit a certain data set, then, several hours later, when they try to submit the same data set again, the operation succeeds without the error.  It's also perplexing that sometimes the Debug button is available and sometimes it isn't.

One issue might be the size of the Access back end; it's currently ~650 MB, and we didn't start getting these messages until it grew to around 600 MB.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?  Various Google hits indicate that this problem sometimes happens when a join query has too many fields, but this is just a recordset of a table, not a join query.

Comment: How many records are being added, and how many rows in the existing table? Have you tried (eg) opening the recordset such that it initially has no rows ("select from tableA where 1=0") and then adding the rows? Or performing batch updates instead of every record? Not a big Access person, so just thoughts off the top of my head...

Comment: @TimWilliams, not very many records--one time the error occurred, the For loop was only iterating through 13 records.  The existing table has ~20K rows.

Comment: if all you are doing is adding records, try `dbAppendOnly` (=8) e.g. `Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(Tbl,dbAppendOnly)`, so that Access does not try to read any records first

Comment: Not sure if this is the [reason](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=286153)

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, methink that this is one of the strange errors that pop-up when you write a lot to a backend database that can't keep up with the management of the lock file.

The solution is to make sure you keep a connection open to the back-end database from each of your client and that you hold onto that connection until you close the client.
Just open a recordset to a table (say a dummy table with only one record), and keep that recordset open until you close the application.

Resource-wise, keeping this connection open will have no detrimental effect on performance or memory consumption, but it will ensure that the lock file is not continuously created/deleted every time a connection is open then closed.

Keeping that connection open will also substantially [increase the performance of your data access](http://immitev.blogspot.hk/2005/01/where-is-ole-db-connection-pooling_28.html).

**Edit:**

You should be more explicit when using recordsets and specify exactly the mode of operation you need:

```
Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(Tbl, dbOpenTable, dbFailOnError)
```

or, faster if you are only appending data:

```
Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(Tbl, dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly + dbFailOnError)
```

Also make absolutely sure you close the recordset once you're finished with appending the data!:

```vb
    Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(Tbl, dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly + dbFailOnError)
    With RS
        'loop through rows in a 2D array
        For i = FR To LR
           .AddNew
              'loop through columns of the 2D array
              For j = 1 To LC
                 'set values for various fields in the new record, 
                 'using values from the array
              Next
           .Update
        Next
        .Close
    End With
    Set RS = Nothing
```

Comment: As noted in the code in the OP, I'm creating a connection with `Set db = OpenDatabase(dbPath)` and not closing that database object until after I'm done inserting all the new rows.  Is this what you mean by "keep a connection open"?

Comment: @sigil it should work yes, the lock file is created and kept while the database is open. I would open the database at the time the client app starts, and only close that connection when the client application is closed by the user, even if you don't need it in between because the issue could occur when multiple clients start adding data at the same time.

Comment: I am already keeping the connection open the whole time (see my original post), that didn't change when I started getting the error.  The error only started once the database reached a certain size, and occurs even when there is only one user.

Comment: @sigil: 1) do you use transactions? 2) Have you tried to compact & repair the database? Maybe there is something we don't see here from the code you shared. Access should have no pb with what you throw at it, and you are fat from reaching the database size limits. 3) Have you tried to move the database to the client machine so they are both on the same PC for a test? 4) Can you show more of the actual code that fails so we get more context?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by running out of available virtual memory (VM) aka swap disk. A 32 bit app cannot use more than 2gb and for some reason Access uses a lot of VM and when it needs more and cannot get any then you run out of system resources.

Solution is to make sure your VM is at least 4 times the RAM and to restart your PC at least daily, only this clears out the VM from garbage left lying around from other apps.

You will never have had this issue on a 32 bit OS, its only now with 64 bit OS that this happens.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Story**
My 3035 error was caused by an add.new to a file without a primary key.

## Composing a copy of the file with a primary key assigned and replacing the key-less file appears to have corrected the problem.

**Long Story**
I have been experiencing 3035 error on an Add.New to an existing backend table with >81,000 records. After searching the web for ideas and coming up dry I reflected on possible issues.

I compacted/repaired the backend files to no affect. Then decided to check the file design. It turns out there was no primary key assigned.

Assigning a primary key to the auto number ID field caused the same 3035 error! So I copied the data structure to a new file, assigned a primary key to the new file and then did a query append of the original file to the new file. Finally I renamed the files.

Using the new file appears to be working.